# SendGrid not sending response to live URL

Tags: php, sendgrid

We are using SendGrid Event Webhook notification to get the information about each delivered email. every time an email delivered to our customer we get notification via HTTP POST on our specific URL.

The URL can be  on either development server or live server.
we tested everything on development server and it worked perfect but when we put live URL on sendgrid-> mail setting -> Event Notification setting page it didn't work and we don't get any response. I searched everywhere and couldn't find the reason. here is the code which get the response from sendgrid. Can anyone tell me is there any confrontational issue or something else is needed.

```
<?php

$result=file_get_contents('php://input');
$response = json_decode($result,true);
```

?>

Comment: Have you tried hitting the live URL with cURL to see if you get the expected result?  Also, if you are using SSL, you may want to try it without in case there is a problem with the certificate negotiation.

Comment: Are development and live servers running in the same environment and setup the same? I agree with Joe above, if you are using SSL on the production site try disabling it or using http just to test without it to eliminate an SSL negotiation issue.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Justin I removed SSL but nothing happend. I tried 'cURL' hint provided by Joe and noticed that it shows 301 Moved Permanently error then I analyze  that our .httaccess converts each page from http://example.com to http://www.example.com it meant I was missing  'www' in the URL specified in sendgrid setting page.. so after putting www it worked perfectly. Thanks Joe.